# Compare two tables and store some of the values in a temporary table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and if table 2 has the highest value compared to table 1,  I want it to be stored in a temporary table.

```
Table 1           Table 2
Fruits    Value   Fruits    Value
Apple      5      Apple       7
Orange     10     Orange      4
Grapes     2      Grapes      6
```

So apple and grapes with values 7 and 6 will be stored to a temporary table. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: Add your sample code upto till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the result:

```
SELECT table2.fruits, table2.value 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.fruits = table2.fruits AND table1.value < table2.value
```

> **Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/346e5/1/0

You can also create a table with all fruits with their highest values from both tables:

```
SELECT fruits, MAX(value) FROM (
    SELECT fruits, value FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT fruits, value FROM table2
)x GROUP BY fruits
```

> **Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/346e5/3/0

To `INSERT` the data into a temporary table you can use the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table3 (
    `fruits` VARCHAR(10),
    `value` INT
);

INSERT INTO tmp_table3 (`fruits`, `value`)
SELECT table2.fruits, table2.value 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.fruits = table2.fruits AND table1.value < table2.value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to merge two tables to temporary table. It can be done by single query.

```
INSERT INTO tmp_table SELECT `Name`, MAX(`Val`) FROM (SELECT `Name`, `Val` FROM table1 UNION SELECT `Name`, `Val` FROM table2) GROUP BY `Name`;
```

If existing items should be replaced, you can use `INSERT OR REPLACE`. If you want to just get result, then use just `SELECT` part of query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.I hope it's help you

```
INSERT INTO `temp`(`fruits`, `value`) SELECT 
  t2.fruits,
  t2.value
FROM `table2` as t2
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.value < t2.value
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: SELECT 
  t2.fruits,
  t2.value
FROM `table2` as t2
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.value < t2.value  this query check and compare value and return table two big value

Comment: Do not use comments to explain your answer.  Please edit your answer and delete your comment.